# ImageView over a TextView

Tags: android, listview, textview, imageview, android-relativelayout

Is there any way, how to put ImageView on a TextView? I've tried to do it many ways but the TextView always hat the "priority" and shown on the top (on the image). Do you have any idea, how to do that?
(Green text on the right - "DNES" is the ImageView and "sobota..." is a TextView)
[image: Whole layout]

XML layouts:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:minHeight="220dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/event_card" >


   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/event_poster"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:src="@drawable/stub_img_new"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:minHeight="90dp"
    android:background="#D9F0F0F0" >


     <cus.haw.sat.ImageViewRounded
        android:id="@+id/event_club_logo"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


     <cus.haw.sat.AutofitTextView
        android:id="@+id/event_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/event_club_logo"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

      <cus.haw.sat.AutofitTextView
        android:id="@+id/event_club_title"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/event_club_logo"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:maxLines="2" />

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/event_today"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_today"
         />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:maxLines="3" />

    </RelativeLayout>


     <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:minHeight="39dp"
    android:background="#D9F0F0F0"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp" > 

         <cus.haw.sat.AutofitTextView
        android:id="@+id/event_bonus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:maxLines="2" />

    </RelativeLayout>





</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, use RelativeLayout or FrameLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of children of a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` controls the Z axis. *Later* children (e.g., later in the XML file) are *higher* on the Z axis. Hence, if you want an `ImageView` to float on top of a `TextView`, make sure the `ImageView` is defined later than the `TextView` as children of the same `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Well, thank you a lot! But I have another problem: if I switch the views (ids: eventToday&eventDaty) the ListView immediately disappears. Dont you know where can be the problem?

Comment: @marson: Not off the top of my head. Use Hierarchy View with your emulator to determine what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, it works now. I just changed id of the textview. Idk why did this happen.

Answer (score 1):

Change children order: "After means below"

This should work ;)